# Remove padding from mat-list-item

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

The `mat-list` component in angular/material2 applies a top and bottom padding of 16px. I'd like to make this 0px. I've tried applying a style with a higher specificity but it isn't working (or I'm doing it wrong).The style I'm trying to override is:

[image: mat-list-item-content style applying 16px padding]

I'm trying to override this with:

```
.list .mat-list .mat-list-item .mat-multi-line .mat-list-item-content {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of queue">
      <h1 matLine>{{ item.id }}: {{ item.status}} {{ item.statusDate }}</h1>
      <p matLine>{{ item.name }}</p>
      <p matLine>for {{ item.customer }}</p>
      <div matLine>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="openTab(item)">
          <mat-icon fontIcon="icon-open"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="showAssignToMe" mat-icon-button (click)="assignToMe(item)">
          <mat-icon fontIcon="icon-assign_to_me"></mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="notes(item)">
          <mat-icon fontIcon="icon-comment"></mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 34):

None of the previous proposions worked for me on Angular 6, 7 & 8

What I proposed is a deprecated solution (https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) but it still continues to work:

```
:host /deep/ .mat-list-item-content {
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: It still works in Angular 7, but I wish I had a better solution

Comment: Yes me too, I dont really like to use deprecated solution ... If you find one, please le met know, I m interested too :)

Comment: I need to remove padding-right when scrollbar exists... Sure wish didn't have to implement deprecated code :/

Comment: @CedricArnould See my answer below

Answer (score 14):

In Angular Material 6, the blank space between list items is not because of padding but due to `.mat-list-item` height. You can get a more compact list with:

```
.mat-list .mat-list-item {
  height: 50px; /* default is 72px */
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Ty

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to turn off the components ViewEncapsulation.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Solved it like this

`:host ::ng-deep .mat-list-item-content { padding: 0!important; }`

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain a little more about that code.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an older question, but I was banging my head trying to figure out how to override padding for the list item text next to a checkbox. The style class I was trying to change was

`.mat-list-base .mat-list-item.mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content .mat-list-text`

which had a left padding of 16px.

The trick is: it has to go in the **root** stylesheet. If you don't want it to apply everywhere, add another class to increase specificity. In my case, I added .less-padding like so:

> `.mat-list-base .less-padding.mat-list-item.mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content .mat-list-text {
>     padding-left: 8px;
>   }`

Add the class to the `<mat-list-option>` tag in your HTML

Comment: This is true and works, but is strongly discouraged by the Materials guidelines since it will likely break during a future upgrade of Materials: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles

Answer (score 4):

```
.mat-list-item{
  max-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: It's better to provide more information. Not just a code.

Answer (score 2):

Just got it by doing this:

```
.mat-list-base .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content {
    padding: 0px !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to remove space between `.mat-list-item` and `.mat-multi-line` because both classes are applied to the same element. In other words use selector:

```
.list .mat-list .mat-list-item.mat-multi-line .mat-list-item-content
```

Answer (score 1):

A fairly reusable method is getting the selectors from DevTools or whatever browser debug tool you are using.

For example, In Chrome: Right-click and inspect the element you want to remove the padding from i.e the `<mat-list-item>` element. In the styles pane filter by padding, or whichever property you are trying to change. You'll see the selectors that are setting padding.

Youll need to copy each one into your CSS/SCSS and add the properties you need. For example, I copied from the styles pane:

```
.mat-list-base[dense] .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content, .mat-list-base[dense] .mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content
```

Use this in your stylesheet. You need to do this for each selector block in the style pane. From the section you've just copied, click the orange tick next to padding. You'll see the `padding` in next selector section below have its strikethroughs removed. Copy that sections selectors to your style sheet. Repeat through this process until you've got all the selectors needed.

My Style sheet ended up looking like this for removing the padding on a `<mat-list-item>`

```
.mat-list-base[dense] .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content, .mat-list-base[dense] .mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content{
    padding: 0 !important;
    
}
.mat-list-base .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content, .mat-list-base .mat-list-option .mat-list-item-content {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of @ian-hoar's answer, **once you have turned off View Encapsulation** asbelow:

```
@Component({
selector: 'list',
templateUrl: './list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**you don't have to rely on `::ng-deep` or `:host ::ng-deep` etc** as they are deprecated.

For instance, if you want to override padding for mat-list-item, all you have to do is

```
.list .mat-list-base .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for those who use Angular 15+
Just add a custom class like that `<mat-list-item class="my-custom-class"></mat-item-list>`
Now add the following lines to the `.css` file of the same component.

```
.my-custom-class.mdc-list-item {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<mat-selection-list ...
    <mat-list-option formfilters *ngFor="let ...
```

SCSS (low level scss like src/styles.scss)

```
.mat-list-option[formfilters] {
    .mat-list-item-content {
        padding: 2px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the styling in your styles.sccs file.

For example,

```
.mat-list-item-content {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Note the use of **!important**, without !important the style will be overriden by the theme.

Comment: Why is this working if I add it to the styles.scss but not if i add it to the stylesheet of the component?

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me

> ```
> <mat-action-list *ngFor="let item of dataSource" style="padding-top: 0%;">
> ```

Comment: this is not the good approach. We should not encourage inline-CSS unless we dont have any option. 
In-line CSS is just like a patch;